# OpenMPI -host and -hostfile options

Tags: openmpi

With OpenMPI v2, when I run a test program with `-host`, it works. I mean, the process spans to the hosts I specified. However, when I specify `-hostfile`, it doesn't work!!

```
mahmood@cluster:mpitest$ /share/apps/computer/openmpi-2.0.1/bin/mpirun -host compute-0-0,cluster -np 2 a.out
****************************************************************************
* hwloc 1.11.2 has encountered what looks like an error from the operating system.
*
* Package (P#1 cpuset 0xffff0000) intersects with NUMANode (P#1 cpuset 0xff00ffff) without inclusion!
* Error occurred in topology.c line 1048
*
* The following FAQ entry in the hwloc documentation may help:
*   What should I do when hwloc reports "operating system" warnings?
* Otherwise please report this error message to the hwloc user's mailing list,
* along with the output+tarball generated by the hwloc-gather-topology script.
****************************************************************************
Hello world from processor cluster.hpc.org, rank 1 out of 2 processors
Hello world from processor compute-0-0.local, rank 0 out of 2 processors
mahmood@cluster:mpitest$ cat hosts
cluster
compute-0-0

mahmood@cluster:mpitest$ /share/apps/computer/openmpi-2.0.1/bin/mpirun -hostfile hosts -np 2 a.out      
****************************************************************************
* hwloc 1.11.2 has encountered what looks like an error from the operating system.
*
* Package (P#1 cpuset 0xffff0000) intersects with NUMANode (P#1 cpuset 0xff00ffff) without inclusion!
* Error occurred in topology.c line 1048
*
* The following FAQ entry in the hwloc documentation may help:
*   What should I do when hwloc reports "operating system" warnings?
* Otherwise please report this error message to the hwloc user's mailing list,
* along with the output+tarball generated by the hwloc-gather-topology script.
****************************************************************************
Hello world from processor cluster.hpc.org, rank 0 out of 2 processors
Hello world from processor cluster.hpc.org, rank 1 out of 2 processors
```

What is the issue then and how can I resolve it?

Comment: OK thanks. I remember I didn't have such problem with previous version 1.6. Is there any reason for that? How can I permanently fix that in order to use less options on the command line. Since other users are not expert and want to run mpi jobs only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hosts listed in the `-host` argument provide one slot each, therefore `-host A,B` means one slot on host `A` and one slot on host `B`.

To force `mpiexec` to launch *N* processes per node, use the following option

```
--map-by ppr:N:node
```

In your case, for one process per node, it should be `--map-by ppr:1:node`. Alternatively, you can limit the number of slots per host to one by modifying the host file to look like this:

```
cluster     slots=1 max_slots=1
compute-0-0 slots=1 max_slots=1
```

(though `slots=1` should be the default if not provided...)

Comment: Is that something other than `-np`?

Comment: `-np` specifies how many processes to start, `--map-by` specifies how to distribute them over the available slots. If you want the MPI program to use all the slots provided by the nodes listed in the host file, you can skip `-np` altogether.